# Java System.err.println latency?

Tags: java, escaping, console-application, system.out, system.err

When I make a Java code like:

```
for (int iRun = 0; iRun <nRun; iRun++){
   doSomething();
   if (100 < nRun && iRun % (nRun / 100) == 0)
      System.err.print("\rWorking " + Math.ceil(100.0 * iRun / nRun) + "%");
}
System.err.println("\rWorking " + Math.ceil(100.0 * iRun / nRun) + "%");
System.err.println("fin");
```

,
it sometime returns

```
Working 100.0%
fin
```

,
bot not always...
it also prints

```
Working 100.0%Working 100.0%
fin
```

.

I do not think, in my codes, any thread calls `System.err#println` at the time.

Even if I put in `Thread.sleep(100);`, it often prints `Working 100.0%` twice. I did not try over 100 sec.(I am not sure it really works and further.... what I tried is not bad..)

How can I make sure that the code prints the first way only??
and if there is a certain answer, it can be used for `System.out::println` as well?

Comment: This code would not compile as you have declared *int iRun = 0* in for loop and have accessed it outside the loop as well.

Comment: Thank you and I found a related question. I may have to get another solution..